# Упорядочить и вывести строки в порядке возрастания значений их длинны

Tags: java, строки, сортировка

Помогите с задачей: Ввести три строки с клавиатуры. Упорядочить и вывести строки в порядке возрастания значений их длинны.

Comment: Если вам разрешается иметь дело с массивами, то вы можете объявить массив из трех строк и отсортировать его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы бы для начала попытались сами хоть что-то написать, задача то пустяковая.
**Код:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] arr = new String[3];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
//Вводим значения в массив (вместо массива лучше использовать конечно же 
//динамическую структуру данных (например ArrayList):
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       arr[i] = in.nextLine();
    }
//Здесь происходит сортировка (сортировка пузырьком):
    for(int i = arr.length-1 ; i > 0 ; i--){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++){
            /*Сравниваем элементы попарно, 
             если они имеют неправильный порядок, 
             то меняем местами */
             if( arr[j].length() > arr[j+1].length() ){
                String tmp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = tmp;
              }
          }
     }
//выводим результат на экран:
     for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
         System.out.println(arr[i]);
     }
}
```

Можно так же воспользоваться методом **sort**, если нужно отсортировать в алфавитном порядке:

```
//заполнение массива
Arrays.sort(arr);
//вывод на экран
```